# matrix expression simplify

Tags: algorithm, matrix, theory

i am wondering if it is possible to simplify:

```
T*V + V*T // V = V^(t) symmetric
```

where both operands are matrixes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think this is possible due to the following considerations:

If we multiply two matrices `A` and `T`, where `A` is symmetric (i.e. `A(i,j) = A(j,i)`), we have the following:

For `A*T` we have that the item in row `z` and column `s` is computed as:

```
 __n__
 \
 /     A(z,i)*T(i,s)
 -----
  i=1
```

For the other way around, `T*A`, we get for row `z`, column `s`:

```
 __n__                     __n__
 \                         \
 /     T(z,i)*A(i,s)  =    /     T(z,i)*A(s,i)
 -----                     -----
  i=1                       i=1
```

So, as long as we do not know anything about the entries `T(i,j)` in `T`, I think we can not say how these sums relate to each other.